# Eliminating circular dependency and create object

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

I have three Projects in my solution

- ClassLibrary   => References  InterfaceLibrary, UIProject
  contains(CountDownTimer.cs)
- InterfaceLibrary
  contains (ICountDownTimer.cs)
- UIProject      => References  InterfaceLibrary
  contains(frmMain.cs, Controller.cs)

I have read that adding interfaces are a way of eliminating circular dependency, I have tried to find an answer to my problem but keep coming up short.

I need to create a new CountDownTimer object in the controller class, can anyone please advise or help

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    //Reference to the Controller class, so we can call it
    private Controller MController { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public frmMain(Controller cntr)
    {
        MController = cntr;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Because controller is the main class, closing the form won't exit the program
        //So we need to close it with an exit call
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MController.StartTimer();
    }
}


public class Controller : ApplicationContext
{
    //Store a reference to the UI
    internal frmMain MainUI { get; set;}
    private ICountDownTimer timer;

    public Controller()
    {

        MainUI = new frmMain(this);
        MainUI.Show();
    }

    internal void StartTimer()
    {

    }
}

public class CountDownTimer : ICountDownTimer
    {
        private int seconds; // Time in seconds
        private int reSetValue; // Time in seconds
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private Controller parent;

        public CountDownTimer(Controller parent, int seconds)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.seconds = seconds;
            reSetValue = seconds;

            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); // Add Handler(timer1_Tick)
            timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second

            //parent.TickUpdate(("" + seconds / 60).PadLeft(2, '0') + "m:" + ("" + seconds % 60).PadLeft(2, '0') + "s");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds--; // Decrement seconds
            if (seconds == 0) // Stop Timer at 0
            {
                timer1.Stop(); // Stop timer
            }
            else
            {
                //parent.TickUpdate(convertSecondToMMSS());

                if (seconds % 60 == 0 || seconds >= 1 && seconds <= 10)
                {
                    //parent.TickUpdate(seconds);
                }
            }
        }

        void ICountDownTimer.StartTimer()
        {
            timer1.Start(); // Start Timer
        }

        public string convertSecondToMMSS()
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
            string str = string.Format("{0:D2}m:{1:D2}s",
                t.Minutes,
                t.Seconds);

            return str;
        }

        void ICountDownTimer.StopTimer()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        void ICountDownTimer.ResetTimer()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            seconds = reSetValue;
            //parent.TickUpdate(convertSecondToMMSS());
        }

        void ICountDownTimer.SetTimer(int seconds)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.seconds = seconds;
            reSetValue = seconds;
            //parent.TickUpdate(convertSecondToMMSS());
        }
    }

public interface ICountDownTimer
{
    void StartTimer();

    void StopTimer();

    void ResetTimer();

    void SetTimer(int seconds);
}
```

Comment: I might be in the minority here, but I've never had a reason to put interfaces in a separate project from their implementation unless there are _additional_ implementations being added in certain special cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CountdownTimer should have no no knowledge of the Controller.

The Controller should instantiate and reference the CountdownTimer and use it's methods and output accordingly e.g. it should subscribe to the timers Tick event handler to update the UI at the correct frequency.

Take a look at the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle) which uses the statement "Don't call us, we'll call you". Applying this stement to your scenario, means that the CountdownTimer shouldn't "call" the Controller, the Controller should "call" the CountdownTimer. In this Wikipedia entry the following excerpt applies exactly to what you are doing:

> The key to make this possible is to sacrifice the element of control.
>   Instead of your program running the system, the system runs your
>   program. In our example, our program could register for timer events,
>   and write a corresponding event handler that updates the coordinates.
>   The program would include other callbacks to respond to other events,
>   such as when the system requires part of a window to be redrawn. The
>   system should provide suitable context information so the handler can
>   perform the task and return. The user's program no longer includes an
>   explicit control path, aside from initialization and registration.

The only concern of the UIProject should be managing the UI. Hence it should not contain the implementation of what can be a generic CountdownTimer class.